# Mean Value Theorem on a Closed Set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

For mean value theorem on the real line, we consider a closed interval $[a,b]$ :

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function on the closed interval $[a,b]$, and differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$. Then there exists some $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that

$$f'(c)=\frac {f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}.$$

However, for the generalization to higher dimensional case (Mean value theorem in several variables) there are multiple sources that define $f$ on an open set. For example, this is adopted from Wikipedia:

Let $G$ be an open convex subset of $\mathbb {R}^{n}$, and let $f:G\to \mathbb {R}$ be a differentiable function. Fix points $x,y\in G$ , and define $g(t)=f((1-t)x+ty)$. Since $g$ is a differentiable function in one variable, then we can apply mean value theorem.

1- **Why is $G$ taken to be an open set?**

2- **And what would be difference if we change it to any arbitrary convex set? (It maight have boundaries but we can define continuity and differentiability at the boundaries).**

Answer (score 2):

1. We want $f$ to be differentiable and it's often supposed by definition (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function) that $f$ is differentiable at point $x$ if $f$ is defined in some neighborhood of $x$. So it's essential that differentiable  $f$ is defined on open set. Otherwise suppose that $f$ is  defined on, for example, closed Cantor set. We may speak about differentiability of $f$, it's possible but not popular.
2. We may change $G$ to any set containing $[x,y]$ as the only thing we need is that  $g(t)=f((1-t)x+ty)$ is a differentiable function in one variable and so we need to know $f(u)$ only for $u \in [x,y]$. But in this case we may have difficulty referring to standard theorems. And it's easier to suppose that $G$ is open.